# excel array formula for divisibility

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Can there be a single formula (maybe an array formula) which can indicate whether the number in F1 is divisible by any of the numbers in the cells (A1:D9)?

[image]

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
{=MIN(MOD(F1, A1:D9))}
```

will be 0 if any of the numbers is a factor.

Comment: Thanks @Tim. This is elegant. I was missing out on combining the mod function with the Min, its very clever actually. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following small user defined function:

```
Public Function IsDivisible(rng As Range, v As Long) As Boolean
    Dim r As Range
    IsDivisible = False

    For Each r In rng
        If v Mod r.Value = 0 Then
            IsDivisible = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next r
End Function
```

For example:

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to **install** and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To **use** the UDF from Excel:

=myfunction(A1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Thanks @Gary's Student. This helps me for now, but I would like to know if its possible to be done without VBA, like an inbuilt function. Thank you for your attention though, it means a lot.

Comment: 1. Could you explain the practical use of Public in this case i.e. in standard module. 2. When I'm assuming that **IsDivisible = False** is here only to make a point and it is by default **False**, is there a case when I could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

## SUMPRODUCT 'Deals' in Arrays

Again, credits to [Tim Williams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/478884/tim-williams) for his brilliant [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55030138/excel-array-formula-for-divisibility/55030452#55030452) and for simply 'forcing' me to  investigate this matter further.

### Formulas

You can use this formula:

> ```
> =IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(MOD(F$1,$A$1:$D$9)=0)),TRUE,FALSE)
> ```

which derived from the formula that counts the number of occurrences of zero remainders:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MOD(F$1,$A$1:$D$9)=0))
```

which brings us to the reason why I would investigate further.

I wanted to exclude `1` and the value in `F1`, `81`, from the occurrences count i.e. if the only zero occurrence is number `1` or `81`, a formula would show `FALSE`, which the following two formulas do:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MOD(F$1,$A$1:$D$9)=0),--($A$1:$D$9>1),--($A$1:$D$9<$F$1))
```

which counts the number of occurrences of zero remainders after dividing the value in `F1` with each value in range `A1:D9`, but not counting if `1` or the value in `F1` where being divided and

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(MOD(F$1,$A$1:$D$9)=0),--($A$1:$D$9>1),--($A$1:$D$9<$F$1)),TRUE,FALSE)
```

which returns `TRUE` if such an occurrence is found, or `FALSE` if not.

### Workbook

[Workbook Download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8gbtsuhwmsr6b06/excel-array-formula-for-divisibility_55030138.xls?dl=0) (Dropbox)

So I played 'a little' in a worksheet to learn a lot.

[image]